# jQuery promise .done() is firing immediately, not waiting for server to return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the .done() event of the promise returned from my $.post() function.  The server-side function it's calling takes five seconds to return.  The problem is the .done() event is firing immediately, as if it's already done.  See my code below.  If I define a success function in-line with the .post() call it works correctly, it's only the .done() event on the promise object that goes right away.  Any idea what I'm missing?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("img.spinner").hide();

        var hideSpinner = function (img) {
            $(img).hide();                
        }

        $("button.Update").click(function () {

            var img = $(this).siblings("img.spinner").show();

            var promise = $.post('/MyFunc/Func',
                function(){
                    $(img).hide();
                }
                );

            promise.done(hideSpinner(img));

        });


    })
```

Comment: Whenever you have as something like `foo(bar())`, `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Arguments are *always* evaluated first, that's how JavaScript works.

Comment: This question is rapidly becoming an old chestnut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `hideSpinner(img)` calls the `hideSpinner` function. It is a function call, not a reference to a function. Try this:

```
promise.done(function () {
    hideSpinner(img)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function reference to done... instead you are invoking the `hideSpinner` function and passing the value returned by it as the done callback.

```
promise.done(function(){
    hideSpinner(img)
});
```